# Need to activate JS code on leaving a textarea

Tags: javascript

Currently I clean text in a TextArea via an an OnClick event on the submit button of a form.

```
<textarea id="comment" class="CleanHTML" cols=70 rows=5></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Save" onClick='document.getElementsByClassName("CleanHTML")[0].value = cleanWordClipboard(document.getElementsByClassName("CleanHTML")[0].value)'>Save</button>
```

However I now think this is flawed, and it would be much better to have the cleanHTML function being triggered on the TextArea element itself when say the user leaves it, so if the user pastes some code then moves on, then it will get triggered.

What would be the required event and what would the function call code now look like?  I provide a starter below with pseudocode in the onblur event, if onblur is the correct event?

```
<textarea id="comment" cols=70 rows=5 onblur="this.value=cleanWordClipboard(this.value)"></textarea>
```

Also what is the best approach to link up all TextAreas to behave this way, centrally. Currently I am thinking that I need to put the required event call on every TextArea.

EDIT1

```
            <script language="JavaScript">
            // Thanks to Johnathan Hedley for this code.
            var swapCodes = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230); // dec codes from char at
            var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'", "'", "\"", "\"", "*", "...");
            function cleanWordClipboard(input) {
                // debug for new codes
                // for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)  alert("'" + input.charAt(i) + "': " + input.charCodeAt(i));    
                var output = input;
                for (i = 0; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
                    var swapper = new RegExp("\\u" + swapCodes[i].toString(16), "g"); // hex codes
                    output = output.replace(swapper, swapStrings[i]);
                }
                return output;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onBlur is the correct event - it triggers when the element loses focus.

Edit:

```
    <textarea id="comment" cols=70 rows=5 onblur="cleanWordClipboard(this)"></textarea>

<script language="JavaScript">
            // Thanks to Johnathan Hedley for this code.
            var swapCodes = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230); // dec codes from char at
            var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'", "'", "\"", "\"", "*", "...");
            function cleanWordClipboard(input) {
                // debug for new codes
                // for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)  alert("'" + input.charAt(i) + "': " + input.charCodeAt(i));    
                var output = input.value;
                for (i = 0; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
                    var swapper = new RegExp("\\u" + swapCodes[i].toString(16), "g"); // hex codes
                    output = output.replace(swapper, swapStrings[i]);
                }
                input.value = output;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the JS code within the call please ie TextArea value = processed TextArea value. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. Any views on my last part of the question: "Also what is the best approach to link up all TextAreas to behave this way, centrally. Currently I am thinking that I need to put the required event call on every TextArea."

Comment: I will close this now, and post last bit as seperate question. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea id="comment" cols=70 rows=5 onblur="cleanWordClipboard(this)" />`

With your JavaScript being:

```
function cleanWordClipboard(control) {
    control.value = "";
}
```

Comment: I have added my JS in EDIT1. So may make a difference

Comment: Exinferis has edited his answer with the corrected JavaScript based on your update

Answer (score 1):

in regards to your last question:

> "Also what is the best approach to link up all TextAreas to behave this way, centrally. Currently I am thinking that I need to put the required event call on every TextArea."

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help you out here.

```
<textarea id="commentA" cols=70 rows=5></textarea>
<textarea id="commentB" cols=70 rows=5></textarea>
<script>
$("textarea").blur(function(){
   cleanWordClipboard(this);
});
</script>
```

Here's a very crude example of it running: http://jsfiddle.net/CatmanDoes/p755m0n8/

I would recommend you don't use it to blindly target all textareas but instead do something like this:

```
<textarea id="commentA" cols=70 rows=5 class="textarea-cleanp"></textarea>
<textarea id="commentB" cols=70 rows=5 class="textarea-cleanp"></textarea>
<script>
$(".textarea-cleanp").blur(function(){
   cleanWordClipboard(this);
});
</script>
```

Whether there's an actual css class for `textarea-cleanp` doesn't matter